# If $f$ and $g$ are analytic in a domain $D$ such that $\overline{f}g$ is also analytic, what is $f$ and $g$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I tried to solve it with Cauchy Riemann equations, let $f = u+iv,g=a+ib$ then we have $u_x = v_y,u_y=-v_x,a_x=b_y,a_y=-b_x$.

Consequently, since $f^{'}g$ is analytic also, we have Cauchy Riemann equation for this as well, $$(au+bv)_x=(bu-av)_y~~~~~~(au+bv)_y= -(bu-av)_x$$

After simplifying, we have $$au_x = bu_y ~~~~~~~bu_x = -au_y$$

Then i am kind of stuck here. The answer to this question is $f$ is a constant in $D$ or $g = 0$ in $D$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $g$ is not identically $0$ in $D,$ then there is a disc $D(a,r)\subset D$ where $g$ doesn't vanish. It follows that $(\bar f g)/g = \bar f$ is analytic in $D(a,r).$

Comment: So $f$ and $\overline{f}$ are both analytic in $D(a,r)$, this implies $f=\overline{f}$ are constants in $D(a,r)$. By uniqueness theorem, $f$ is constant in the domain $D$. So the proof ends. However, is this question asking us to show that $f$ is a constant on the whole complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ or just on this domain $D$? Thanks!